# How do I get the RabbitMQ dead letter header information out of a message in EasyNetQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

This is a followup to a previous question I asked:

[How do I deserialize a dead lettered message when dead lettering changes the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426854/how-do-i-deserialize-a-dead-lettered-message-when-dead-lettering-changes-the-typ)

The problem I'm having now is that I can't see the extra header info that RabbitMQ adds when a message dead letters.

The extra header info is under "x-death" and they are count, reason, queue, time, exchange and routing-keys.   Once EasyNetQ deserializes the message back into my custom message class, this header info seems to vanish.  Is there any way to still access it from inside my C# application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no way to do it using regular EasyNetQ. But there is an extension for that purpose [EasyNetQ.MetaData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasyNetQ.MetaData/) . As the documentation of it states, it is obviously possible using the advanced [EasyNetQ API](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/the-advanced-api).